# Are C# Proto3 classes immutable?

Tags: c#, immutability, proto3

I'm passing a reference type (Proto3 generated) to a method to update some properties. When the method returns, the properties have reverted back as if it's not being passed by reference or are immutable.

```
MyData dest = new MyData();
dest.Num = 1;

MyData src = new MyData();
src.Num = 2;

Console.WriteLine(dest.Num); // num = 1
Test(src, dest);
Console.WriteLine(dest.Num); // num still equals 1

public static void Test(MyData src, MyData dest)
{
    // dest.Num = 1 here
    dest = src;
    // dest.Num = 2 now
}
```

Comment: You've just changed the value of the `dest` parameter. That's a parameter which is passed by value - you're not using `ref`. If instead you used `dest.Num = 3;` that would change the content of the object that `dest` refers to. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html - note that this has nothing to do with Protobuf, it's just how C# works in general.

Comment: I actually just read your article yesterday trying to wrap my head around this. Just to validate, value types and reference types are passed by value unless you use the `ref` keyword. However you can still modify the data the reference type references without `ref`. You just can't change the actual reference itself?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you haven't read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html yet, I'd read that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` and `dest` are passed by value. When you assign `dest=src`, you're just assigning `src` to a local variable that used to point to `dest`, which does not affect `dest` itself.

You can, of course, modify `dest` inside a method by modifying its members if you want to, e.g.:

```
public static void Test(MyData src, MyData dest)
{
    dest.Num = src.Num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your choice to reuse variable names may be confusing the problem. Let's fix that:

```
MyData foo = new MyData();
foo.Num = 1;

MyData bar = new MyData();
bar.Num = 2;

Console.WriteLine(foo.Num); // num = 1
Test(bar, foo);
Console.WriteLine(foo.Num); // num still equals 1

public static void Test(MyData src, MyData dest)
{
    // dest.Num = 1 here
    dest = src;
    // dest.Num = 2 now
}
```

Now let's look at what `Test` does.  It *reassignes* the value of `dest` to `src`. It does NOT change the values of the object that either `dest` or `src` referenced at all. So `foo` and `bar` in the calling function still reference the same objects, so your result is expected.

If you have made `dest` a `ref` variable in `Test`, *then* you would have seen `foo` change because `Test` would change the actual reference.